# Avoiding explicit 'any' with Chart.js v3

Tags: typescript, chart.js, chart.js3

We recently upgraded our Chart.JS library from v2 to v3, in part to make use of the new, integrated type annotations in our TypeScript code, however we've run into a number of issues where we've been forced to use an explicit "any" type cast in order to make the code work.  Is there anyway around this?

Example:
Setting a ChartDataset to present as a dotted line:

```
(cds as any).borderDash = [10, 5];
```

Works as intended, but if we don't add the explicit any cast we fail to compile with errors like:

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/bbowman/git/dragen-plots2/src/lib/plots/mbias_tool.ts(42,13)
TS2339: Property 'borderDash' does not exist on type 'ChartDataset<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[]>'.
Property 'borderDash' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type: "bar"; } & BarControllerDatasetOptions> & ChartDatasetProperties<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | ... 2 more ... | null)[]>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cast it to the correct type in this case it's the line dataset:

```js
(cds as ChartDataset<"line">).borderDash = [10, 5];
```